# Cross-platform event listeners in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Can Instances of Node.js `EventEmitter` class, listen to the event notifications from different platforms such as C or C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want implement platform-independent event system you may look to any message broker such as RabbitMQ. Or you can implement it using Redis PUB/SUB.

Answer (score 2):

If you create an `EventEmitter` you have to emit the event on this instance. If you want to trigger events in C/C++ you have to write an interface for it. You will find a starting points in the [node-gyp repo](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp).

Answer (score 1):

> Can Instances of Node.js `EventEmitter` class, listen to the event notifications from different platforms such as C or C++?

No, not directly.  A node.js `EventEmitter` class only works in Javascript (its implementation is entirely Javascript) so in order to trigger an event, some Javascript must call `.emit()` in Javascript on the EventEmitter object in your node.js process.

If you had some C or C++ code running somewhere and you wanted to trigger an event in an `EventEmitter`, then you'd have to somehow call some Javascript code in node.js from your C/C++ code that could then call a method (in Javascript) on the `EventEmmitter` object.

If your C/C++ code was inside a node.js native code add-on, then you could probably trigger some sort of callback into Javascript from your C/C++ code the same way other node internals that are implemented in C/C++ can trigger callbacks (such as the implementation of `setTimeout()`).  If your C/C++ code was in another process (e.g. not inside of node.js already), then you'd have to do some sort of inter-process communication to the node.js process (like an http request) to connect to some code in node.js to ask it to do something on your behalf (like emit an event).